# How to get index of array inside document

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to sort `mRecipies` list by timeMillis but since timeMillis are saved in document as array, I cant get my `dateWhenSetFavorites` array index.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPQaL.jpg

Tried to think for solutions but couldn't figure it out.

```
Collections.sort(mRecepies, new Comparator<RecipeModel>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(RecipeModel o1, RecipeModel o2) {
    return (int)(o1.getFavouriteRecipeModels().get(0).getDateWhenSetFavourite() - o2.getFavouriteRecipeModels().get(0).getDateWhenSetFavourite());
  }
});
```

How can I structure my database or get index each time? In my code I typed `get(0)` witch is not universal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Doug Stevenson mentioned in his answer, there is no way you can sort anything that appears in an array but there is a workaround. If you are allowed to make some database schema changes, I recommend you create another collection like this:

```
Firestore-root
    |
    --- favoriteRecipeModels (collection)
            |
            --- uid (document)
                 |
                 --- userFavoriteRecipeModels (collection)
                         |
                         --- recipeId
                               |
                               --- dateWhenSetFavorite: 1564...5677
                               |
                               --- recipeId: "tC19...CmiT"
                               |
                               --- recipeMealType: "Blynai"
                               |
                               --- userId: "tx9O...4jd2"
```

To get all favorite recipes of a single user, you can simply use:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
db.collection("favoriteRecipeModels").document("uid").collection("userFavoriteRecipeModels");
```

Or a more simple schema that require a query with a `wehereEqualTo()` call would be:

```
Firestore-root
    |
    --- favoriteRecipeModels (collection)
            |
            --- recipeId
                   |
                   --- dateWhenSetFavorite: 1564...5677
                   |
                   --- recipeId: "tC19...CmiT"
                   |
                   --- recipeMealType: "Blynai"
                   |
                   --- userId: "tx9O...4jd2"
```

And the required query should be:

```
db.collection("favoriteRecipeModels").whereEqualTo("userId", uid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firestore doesn't support sorting by anything that appears in an array.  You will have to store the data to sort by in another field.

Comment: But how ? I want to set to adatper recipes for users by recipe type they saved and order by dateWhenSetFavorite ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try firebase index feature for sorting Collection

refer this link:https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing